# How can I avoid throttling when batch writing a large number of items to AWS DynamoDB table?

Tags: python, csv, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a large csv file (~25k rows) and I am trying to automatically import these items to a AWS DynamoDB table. I wrote a lambda function that is triggered when the csv is uploaded to an S3 bucket and then uses batch writing to put items into a DynamoDB table. The problem I'm having is that I think the DB table is throttling. My lambda function times out after 15 minutes, and only about 3k items have been put into the table after that time. Is there a way to alter my code to avoid throttling? I found that exponential backoff and jitter could be a solution, but I've searched a lot online and can't find a good way to implement this into my code. Or if anyone has another suggestion on how to fix this problem, I'm all ears!

Also, I'm writing my lambda function in python. Here's the code:

```
import json
import io
import csv 
import boto3 
import pandas as pd
from decimal import Decimal

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = dynamodb.Table('batch-gun-data-test')

    bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    s3_file_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    csvfile = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=s3_file_name)

    chunks = (chunk for chunk in csvfile["Body"].iter_chunks(chunk_size=1024**3))
    data = io.BytesIO(b"".join(chunks)) # This keeps everything fully in memory
    df = pd.read_csv(data, sep='\t')

    df2 = df[['SKU', 'SubCategory' ]].copy()


    # item = json.loads(json.dumps(item), parse_float=Decimal)

    with table.batch_writer() as batch: 
        # for i, row in df.iterrows():
        #     print(row.to_dict())
            # batch.put_item(Item=row.to_dict())
        for i, record in enumerate(df2.to_dict("records")):
            batch.put_item(Item=record)
```

I've also tried changing the WCU on the DynamoDB table, but this doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: The reason I'm copying the data into another data frame is because I was having an issue with one of my columns, so I just wanted to get the code working with two columns before I tackle the one causing me problems.

Comment: We need to know whats causing your throttling. You changed the WCU, to what? Have you tried On-demand mode?

Comment: Are you being throttled when in On-demand mode?

Comment: I tried changing to on-demand mode and it seems to have fixed the throttling. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I see two major issues with the setup:

1. Relaying on AWS Lambda to do heavy lifting work, processing (~25k) rows. Ideally, AWS Lambda is designed to do low-latency light repetitive tasks. That means, we need to split the big files into small files and process them separately one after another.
2. Write-capacity of DynamoDB. Even on-demand capacity takes some time to scale up/scale down the capacity throughput. This means we need to have a system in place, that will ingest data into DynamoDB within a restricted capacity.

Since your use case is likely to generate spiky traffic and then stay idle for a longer time. Therefore, you would need to pay whenever you are using AWS resources. Therefore, I can suggest you use the following workaround:

[image]

1. When you upload any CSV file. Lambda will be triggered and it will split that file into multiple files and save those into **separate** S3 buckets.
2. Following the first step. Another lambda instance will spin up and that will write into the SQS.
3. You will have a lightweight poller service, polling SQS. It will pick those events from SQS and save them into DDB. *Make sure you don't spin up too many polling and worker threads, otherwise, this may even lead to DDB throttling issue.*

Hope this helps!